# AWS Lambda unittest cases throwing errors

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a AWS lambda which is invoking another lambda, I am creating unittest file for the same, following is my source code.

sample_lambda.py

```
client = boto3.client('lambda')
   def lambda_handler(event,context):
         t_json = json_parser(event)
         response = client.invoke(
                     FunctionName='FuctionARN', InvocationType='RequestResponse'
                     Payload = json.dumps(t_json))
         status_code = response["StatusCode"]
         return status_code
```

json_parser will take event json as input, parse it and return the json object.

Test file test_sample_lambda.py - Throwing an error

```py
from sample_lambda import lambda_handler
import unittest
from unittest import mock

class Testsamplelambda(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch("boto3.client")
    def test_lambda_handler(self, mock_client):
        mock_client.return_value = mock_client
        expected = "{'status_code':'200'}"
  
        test_event = {
                     "Records":[{
                         "data":[
                              {
                               }]
                      }]  
              }              
       actual = lambda_handler(test_event,{})
       self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

Error Message: test_lambda_hander() takes two positional arguments but 3 were given

Can someone share ideas how to fix this issue.

Comment: any inputs please

Comment: Awaiting for inputs, please help here if someone knows this issue.

Comment: Please also share how you're invoking the tests, what version of Python you're using, and any other packages that might be involved, since I cannot reproduce this issue.